# Oracle - Query doesn't show results on select but insert the records

Tags: sql, database, oracle, parallel-processing

I have the following insert query:

```
   INSERT INTO dmf_val_error_log
   WITH min_loc_trait AS
   (
      SELECT h.loc_trait,
             h.description    loc_trait_desc,   -- To compare with this brand division (last 3 CHARS of div_name)
             d.STORE,
             --- MIN(d.loc_trait) OVER (PARTITION BY d.STORE) store_min_loc_trait,
             COUNT(*)         OVER (PARTITION BY d.STORE) store_cnt
        FROM mig_loc_traits        h,
             mig_loc_traits_matrix d
       WHERE h.loc_trait = d.loc_trait
   ),
   this_brand_loc_trait AS
   (
      SELECT mlt.loc_trait,
             regexp_substr(mlt.loc_trait_desc, '[^_]+', 1, 2) brand,
             mlt.store
        FROM min_loc_trait  mlt,
             mig_division   d
      WHERE d.div_name LIKE regexp_substr(mlt.loc_trait_desc, '[^_]+', 1, 2) || '_' || '%'
      GROUP BY mlt.loc_trait,
               regexp_substr(mlt.loc_trait_desc, '[^_]+', 1, 2),
               mlt.store
   ),
   valid_brand_loc_trait AS
   (
      SELECT d.loc_trait,
             regexp_substr(d.loc_trait_desc, '[^_]+', 1, 2) brand,
             d.store
        FROM min_loc_trait d
       WHERE regexp_substr(d.loc_trait_desc, '[^_]+', 1, 2) = 'DEB'
         AND d.store_cnt - 1 = 1
         AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM this_brand_loc_trait bvs
                      WHERE bvs.STORE = d.store)
       GROUP BY d.loc_trait,
                regexp_substr(d.loc_trait_desc, '[^_]+', 1, 2),
                d.store
      UNION ALL
      SELECT d.loc_trait,
             d.brand,
             d.store
        FROM this_brand_loc_trait d
   )
   SELECT 
          'BRAND/ATTRIBUTE_1/ATTRIBUTE_2=S combination does not match any existing MIG_LOC_TRAITS/MIG_LOC_TRAITS_MATRIX setup',   -- error_desc
     FROM mig_als_int_cross_ref_dmf_ccid crs,
          v_brand_store                  s
    WHERE crs.attribute_2 = 'S'
      AND crs.attribute_1 = s.store
      AND s.is_store_min_brand = 'Y'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM valid_brand_loc_trait lt
                       WHERE lt.store  = TO_NUMBER(crs.attribute_1)
                         AND lt.brand = crs.brand);
```

When I run the underlying SQL statement, it doesn't bring any record.
But If I run with the inserts, it inserts records on it.

The following statement is executed initially on the server:

```
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML PARALLEL 50;
```

If this statement is executed and then the insert is run, it inserted records.
But if this parallel statement is not executed, the insert query doesn't insert anything.

What can be the issue with the above parallel force and the query?

**UPDATE: - Use Case**

1. When running the Select statement under the Insert, it brings 0-Records
   [image]
2. Just by un-commenting the insert, it inserts records from the same SQL
   [image]

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a bug.  Have you reported the bug to Oracle support?  Have you applied the most recent patchset for whatever version of Oracle you're using?

Comment: can you provide a test case where you show us this behaviour ?

Comment: When you say *"it doesn't bring any record."* do you mean it returns an empty set or it just hangs without returning anything? It seems like you mean the latter, because something happens when you run in parallel. In which case this is a tuning problem. Please read [this excellent post on asking Oracle tuning questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325). It describes the information you need to provide before we can offer sensible performance advice (rather than just guesses).

Comment: I mean that it brings 0-records. On further analysis, it doesn't; seem to execute the last clause - that is NOT EXISTS.  If I just run the underlying select statements, it brings 0 records. If I place the Insert, it brings 183 records.

Comment: Question updated with the screenshots

Comment: get the execution plan for each version (i.e. with and without the insert), and check if any predicate is missing. You did not say which case is good: the zero rows or the 183.